# why does the sequelize transaction t.lock.UPDATE do not block the other transaction?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, postgresql-9.3

```
            var promises = [];
            promises.push(
                sequelize.transaction(function(t1) {
                    return models.car_service.findAll({
                        where: sequelize.and(
                            { "id_dtc": 6},
                            { "id_car": 95 }
                        ),
                        transaction: t1,
                        lock: t1.LOCK.UPDATE,
                        logging: console.log
                    }).then(function(result) {
                        console.log(result.dataValues);
                        if(!result.dataValues){
                        return models.car_service.create(
                            {
                                id_dtc: 6,
                                id_car: 95,
                                priority: config.get('apiConfig.coreControllerConfig.createIssueOptions.DTCPriority'),
                                status: 'new',
                                dtc_is_pending: false
                            });
                        }
                    })
                })
            );
            promises.push(
                sequelize.transaction(function(t2) {
                    return models.car_service.findAll({
                        where: sequelize.and(
                            { "id_dtc": 6},
                            { "id_car": 95 }
                        ),
                        transaction: t2,
                        lock: t2.LOCK.UPDATE,
                        logging: console.log
                    }).then(function(result) {
                        console.log(result.dataValues);
                        if(! result.dataValues){
                        return models.car_service.create(
                            {
                                id_dtc: 6,
                                id_car: 95,
                                priority: config.get('apiConfig.coreControllerConfig.createIssueOptions.DTCPriority'),
                                status: 'new',
                                dtc_is_pending: false
                            });
                        }
                    })
                })
            );
            return promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
                console.log(results);
            });
```

the log is

```
Executing (14a1c614-c2f1-46a1-a99f-89bc92ca23dc): SELECT "id", "status",        "priority", "mileage", "done_at", "created_at", "updated_at", "id_car",   "id_service_type", "id_service_edmunds", "id_service_customized", "id_recall_recallmasters", "id_service_archive", "id_service_mmy", "id_service_preset", "id_dtc", "dtc_is_pending" FROM "car_service" AS "car_service" WHERE ("car_service"."id_dtc" = 6 AND "car_service"."id_car" = 95) FOR UPDATE;
Executing (084558cc-730d-441a-a794-aaa27898db77): SELECT "id", "status", "priority", "mileage", "done_at", "created_at", "updated_at", "id_car", "id_service_type", "id_service_edmunds", "id_service_customized", "id_recall_recallmasters", "id_service_archive", "id_service_mmy", "id_service_preset", "id_dtc", "dtc_is_pending" FROM "car_service" AS "car_service" WHERE ("car_service"."id_dtc" = 6 AND "car_service"."id_car" = 95) FOR UPDATE;

undefined
undefined
```

Does anyone know why I am still adding 2 same rows in the table, i thought the row lock should block the transaction that have a select for update?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass in the respective transaction object `{transaction: t1}` or `{transaction: t2}` as option in the second query of the transactions.

Refer to the example ([in the documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html))